# Creating a loop in my guessing game

Tags: c#

How do I repeat this code/game if the player gets the answer wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random RandomGenerator = new Random();// random number generator
            Console.WriteLine("i have thought of a number between 1 and 100");//display message
            //
            //
            int IN_RandomNum = RandomGenerator.Next(1, 100); //the range
            //loop 10 times 
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) //for loop created
            {
                int IN_Guess; //guessing integer
                Console.Write("{0} turns left, enter your next guess>", 10 - i);//number of turns players has 
                //
                IN_Guess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); //string to number
                //Now check if guess is same as generated 
                if (IN_Guess == IN_RandomNum)//if guess is equal to generated number
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("correct in {0} turns", i + 1); //if guessed correctly 
                    break; //breaking code
                }
                else if (IN_Guess > IN_RandomNum) //if guess is higher than generated number
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Too high");// if guessed number is too high
                }
                else //then...
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Too low"); // if guessed number is too low
               } if (i==8) //on last turn display this message
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("*YOU ONLY HAVE 1 GUESS LEFT!*"); //display this message 
                }

            }

            Console.WriteLine("please press enter to quit"); //display message
            Console.ReadLine();//keeps application open until enter button hit
        }
    }
}
```

Please help because i really cant figure out where to put the while loop...ive ran out of ideas

Comment: Could you describe your problem? You already have for loop. It should be just enough

Comment: Enclose your whole code in another loop, such as `while(1)` or `while(someCondition)`

Answer (score 0):

You would need to wrap everything in a while loop.

When it exits the for loop you have, it doesn't matter if they win or lose you go back to the top and start again, generating a new random number.

**Before reading the code below, see my suggestion above and attempt it yourself, see if you can crack it**

Something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Random RandomGenerator = new Random();// random number generator

    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("i have thought of a number between 1 and 100");//display message
        bool guessedCorrect = false;
        int IN_RandomNum = RandomGenerator.Next(1, 100); //the range
                                                            //loop 10 times 
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) //for loop created
        {
            int IN_Guess; //guessing integer
            Console.Write("{0} turns left, enter your next guess>", 10 - i);//number of turns players has 
                                                                            //
            IN_Guess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); //string to number
                                                            //Now check if guess is same as generated 
            if (IN_Guess == IN_RandomNum)//if guess is equal to generated number
            {
                Console.WriteLine("correct in {0} turns", i + 1); //if guessed correctly 
                guessedCorrect = true;
                break; //breaking code
            }
            else if (IN_Guess > IN_RandomNum) //if guess is higher than generated number
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Too high");// if guessed number is too high
            }
            else //then...
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Too low"); // if guessed number is too low
            }
            if (i == 8) //on last turn display this message
            {
                Console.WriteLine("*YOU ONLY HAVE 1 GUESS LEFT!*"); //display this message 
            }
        }

        if (guessedCorrect)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Good job... Lets try again");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Better luck next timer... here we go");
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. I lost every time i tried, your game is too hard :-(